# Sprite-Kit : Sprite z-Order

Tags: sprite-kit

How to Change Sprite's z-Order in Sprite-Kit?

Cocos2d Code:

```
[parentNode addChild:sprite1 z:3];
[parentNode addChild:sprite2 z:2];
[parentNode addChild:sprite3 z:1];
```

I tried below code in Sprite-Kit..but its not changing z-order

```
[parentNode insertChild:sprite1 atIndex:3];
[parentNode insertChild:sprite2 atIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For draw order use the [`zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/zPosition) property of a node:

> **zPosition** The height of the node relative to its parent.
>
> The default value is
>   0.0. The positive z axis is projected toward the viewer so that nodes with larger z values are closer to the viewer. When a node tree is
>   rendered, the height of each node (in absolute coordinates) is
>   calculated and then all nodes in the tree are rendered from smallest z
>   value to largest z value. If multiple nodes share the same z position,
>   those nodes are sorted so that parent nodes are drawn before their
>   children, and siblings are rendered in the order that they appear in
>   their parent’s children array. Hit-testing is processed in the
>   opposite order.
>
> The SKView class’s `ignoresSiblingOrder` property controls whether node
>   sorting is enabled for nodes at the same z position.

You can also use `insertChild:atIndex:` to affect z order but keep in mind that index is the index of the object in the array, not it's `zPosition` (ie `atIndex` parameter is not the same as the `z` parameter in cocos2d, in fact it's the inverse). Nodes added at a lower index will be drawn before nodes at a higher index.

Also note that you can't insert nodes at an index out of bounds. From the [NSMutableArray docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject%3aatIndex%3a)

> [..] you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the
>   current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two
>   objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2.
>   Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds; if you try to add an object at
>   index 3 (when the size of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an
>   exception.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have `ignoresSibingOrder` enabled, but the sprites with the same zPosition still are still rendering in the order I've added them to their parent. Will this be unreliable? I feel like I would have to explicitly set proper zPositions if I need some sprites to draw in front of others with `ignoresSiblingOrder` set to true, but I haven't so far.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift you can do:

```
sprite.zPosition = 1
```

---

Usually the **zOrder** is , **just to make an example**:

**-1** (put it to the back)

**0** (in the middle, it's also the default value)

**1** (put it in front of all)

When all your objects **have the same `zPosition`** (for example the default 0.0) and they are added to the same parent node, **the order** they appear **is estabilished by the "`addChild`" order** in your code: **the last is in front of all**.

Answer (score 1):

I always use just:

```
sprite.zPosition = 13;
```

If I want it to be on zPosition 13. The higher the zPosition the closer the sprite is to the user, and it will be rendered and displayed over the sprites that have smaller zPosition.

Answer (score 1):

[image: from Apple Documentary for sprite kit]
Forexample, Think here, there are a sky node and a helicopter node has 4 child node Missiles, body, rotor 1 and rotor 2. We want rotor 1 and rotor 2 upper from body, and missiles below from body.

[image: second image]

Give the sky's .zPosition = 0, this gives sky has default zPosition.
and give the body.zPosition = 100 it will above from sky and body will be visible above sky. And child nodes rotor1, rotor2 and missile. Give the z position of Rotor 1 and Rotor 2 z = +1, this gives upper from body and give the missile's zPosition z= -1, it gives below from the body.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, us the node's `zPosition` property. But if you don't want to track all the various zPositions of all the nodes in you scene, you can put you Sprite at a relative depth to another e.g.:

```
newSprite.zPosition = anotherSprite.zPosition + 1
```

to put newSprite just in front of anotherSprite. I also save 100 and -100 for sprites that have to be right at the front or back etc, no matter what also is in the scene.