# how to decide the order in which the nodes appear in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Is there any way I can completely control the order in which the nodes in a sprite kit scene appear. I am trying to make a very simple game but the order in which my nodes appear seems to be random. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about the ignoresSiblingOrder method of the SKView Class and also the zPosition property of a node.

Full documentation has been given on this link with an example -

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll have a look and post here if I have any further questions.

Comment: found this explanation by @LearnCocos2D here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304807/sprite-kit-sprite-z-order