# Nodes spawning behind background and I can't bring them to the front

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, repeater, nodes

I'm using a repeat action. When the app first loads the sprites do spawn in front of the background and so you can see them. But then when you restart the game from the score scene, the nodes spawn behind the background and I can't get them to come to the front. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
    override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    //Background
    for var index = 0; index < 2; ++index {
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: -100, y: index * Int(bg.size.height))
        bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bg.name = "background"
        self.addChild(bg)
    }
     runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(callEnemy), SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))
```

The `runAction` is the code to repeat an action that doesn't seem to be working

```
    //Player functions
    foreground = SKNode()
    addChild(foreground)
    player = createPlayer()
    foreground.addChild(player)
    //Game hud
    gameHud = SKNode()
    addChild(gameHud)
}

    func callEnemy() {
    if player.physicsBody?.dynamic == true {
        spawnEnemy()
    }
}

    func spawnEnemy() -> SKNode{

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy1")
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * random(min: 0, max: 1), y: 690 )
    addChild(enemy)

    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemy.size.width / 2)
    enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: enemy.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: -200.0)
    enemy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    if enemy.position.y <= CGFloat(0) {
        enemy.removeFromParent()
    }
    return enemy
}
```

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304807/sprite-kit-sprite-z-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the nodes be on top of the background you need to change their `zPosition`. If you specify:

```
bg.zPosition = 0
```

and

```
foreground.zPosition = 1
```

the foreground will now be on top of the background. The zPosition specifies the location of each node on the z-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much it has worked, i have literally spent the past 3 days trying to get it to work, thanks

Comment: No problem glad it worked! Just accept my answer/ +1 it so others know it works @Vince